# R - Error running pkg:NCStats z.test example

Tags: r

I was trying to generate some plots for t, z and chi-square test. I found an example with TeachingDemos package. The link [here](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/NCStats/plot.htest.html). The codes and corresponding error is as follows,

```
> library(TeachingDemos)
> z.ex <- z.test(rnorm(25,100,5),99,5)
> z.ex
    One Sample z-test
data:  rnorm(25, 100, 5) 
z = 3.0926, n = 25, Std. Dev. = 5, Std. Dev. of the sample mean = 1, p-value
= 0.001984
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 99 
95 percent confidence interval:
 100.1326 104.0525 
sample estimates:
mean of rnorm(25, 100, 5) 
                 102.0926 
> plot(z.ex)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
>
```

I am using, R 2.13 on a Ubuntu 11.10 laptop. 
Anybody can tell me what should I do to plot what I wanted?

_Have a nice weekend.

_HM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to install NCStats (which apparently adds a plot method for the htest class that is not present in TeachingDemos) you will need to download and install it. I wasn't able to convince my GUI installer to use RForge as a repository, so after downloading to my /User/username/ directory, I executed this commapnd at an R command line:

```
install.packages("~/NCStats_0.2-7.tar.gz",
  "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/" , # to put into my System R lib
           type="source")
```

Comment: The install package for `NCStats` gives `source("http://www.rforge.net/NCStats/InstallNCStats.R")` -- which seems to work for me (as does the example above)

Comment: I had the same problem like you while trying to install NCStats in RStudio. Then I have downloaded the package and installed it like what you said and everything is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your link points to an *RForge* package called `NCStats`.

Your code loads a package called `TeachingDemos`.

The two are not the same.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance. could you please give me any tips how to draw the plots of t/chi/z-distribution with marked points?

Comment: Thanks. It's the clue I need to have. I thought I need only TeachingDemos package. Thanks for the help. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded the package NCStats?
If not try to load it with library(NCStats)

Comment: actually i thought the TeachingDemos would be sufficient. I am now following DWin's suggestion to install it and try again.